# where does the apostrophe go in this sentence?

Tags: apostrophe

Where would the apostrophe go in:

'he dedicated his days to...'

Would it be days, day's or days'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option is correct, there is no apostrophe.

The possessive in this sentence is in 'his' which does not require an apostrophe, and 'days' is a simple plural.

Comment: Please do not answer questions obviously inappropriate for inclusion on a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: Sorry, was my question inappropriate?

Comment: @samuel lee I'm not sure that ELL, ELU's sister site for more basic questions, would welcome so basic and flawed a question. There's nothing wrong with the question in itself, but it's addressing something one would expect to be understood early in the mastering of English. ELU is aimed at linguists.

Comment: Wow, ok. I didn't realise someone would feel the need to comment on my question after it had been answered just to say that it was too stupid a question in the first place, but each to their own. I just thought that with a site name English Language and Usage it may be able to help me. The powers that be should consider changing the name of the site to Edwin Ashworth's Little Power Trip Board. I'm sorry, Edwin, I'll leave the site to professional linguists, like yourself.